# What is the correct and better language code format in URL and hreflang?

Tags: seo, url, multilingual

From SEO perspective, which language code format in the URL is better and more correct?
www.example.com/en-US
www.example.com/en_US

Is the second format valid for the attribute `hreflang` in `<link rel="alternate".....>`?
According to [the Google guideline](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en&topic=2370587&ctx=topic), the first format `en-US` is always described.

I have already done my website with the second format `en_US`. Is it worth to move to the first format if it is a better one.

## [UPDATE]

Rather than trying to find an answer to choose underscores or dashes in URL, I would like to know about the correct language code usage in URL. For example, as I already used the `en_US` format, what is the correct usage?

`<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/en_US" hreflang="en_US" />` 
`<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/en_US" hreflang="en-US" />`